# Getting change notification in Lit when using Angular property bindings

Tags: angular, lit

We're trying to integrate a Web Component built with Lit into an angular application. The web component has a property whose changes need to trigger some special logic to reload data from a server:

```
@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
    @property({type: String})
    myUrl = '';

    override async attributeChangedCallback(
        name: string,
        old: null | string,
        value: null | string
    ) {
       super.attributeChangedCallback(name, old, value);
       if (name === 'myUrl' && value && value !== old) {
           // We need trigger the fetching of data manually, when
           // the attribute changes.
           await this.fetchData();
      }
   }   
}
```

If we try to use property binding in Angular for this property, the `attributeChangedCallback` is never called:

```html
 <my-component [myUrl]="'https://example.com/test.json'" >   
 </my-component>
```

It works if we statically set the value:

```html
 <my-component myUrl="https://example.com/test.json" >   
 </my-component>
```

If I add a `hasChanged` callback to the `myUrl` property, it is called when using the Angular property binding. However, I can't access the instance of the web component in `hasChanged`, so I can't trigger the reload.

How do you get change notifications in Lit when using Angular property bindings?

Answer (score 0):

To set values for attributes directly, you should prefix the name of the attribute with `attr` followed by a dot.

```
<my-component [attr.myUrl]="'https://example.com/test.json'" >   
 </my-component>
```

[More about attribute bindings](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)